# How to understand Redis Monitor output?

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I'm working with a redis instance locally with a PHP app.
I'm getting the following output from `redis-cli monitor`:

```
1550597216.002208 [1 127.0.0.1:36484] "DEL" "XXXXXX:1745715486"
```

The key-value is still there but if I do it with `redis-cli`

```
127.0.0.1:6379> DEL XXXXXX:1745715486
```

I get the following log:

```
1550597346.838962 [0 127.0.0.1:36284] "DEL" "XXXXXX:1745715486"
```

I see the difference with the two logs (`0` instead of `1` between the brackets) but there is no documentation on what that number means.

Do you happens to know its meaning ?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the number of the database. The DEL operation was made on another database than the one I used for GET and SET.